# Differences in PipelineDB and AWS Kinesis Analytics use of Reference data

Tags: amazon-kinesis, pipelinedb

I'm doing a comparison of AWS Kinesis Analytics to PipelineDB use of "reference" data in STREAM SQL.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisanalytics/latest/dev/limits.html
http://docs.pipelinedb.com/joins.html#joins

Question 1: JOIN on multiple reference tables

AWS Kinesis Analytics - only lets you join to reference data from one source. 
That seems really restrictive!  Unless I am not understanding it.  I'd want to be able to JOIN on say, USERS, and an ADDRESS reference data.  I can't?

PipelineDB - says it supports JOINs, but the docs don't have JOIN examples to multiple reference tables.  Does PipelineDB support joining multiple reference tables in it's STREAMS and/or CONTINUOUS VIEWs?

Question 2:  Refreshing reference data

AWS Kinesis Analytics - says you have to jump through some hoops (e.g. calling AWS APIs, etc.) to refresh reference data stored in its S3 bucket for the stream

PipelineDB - Can streams simply get the latest reference data as it is updated using standard SQL updates to the reference tables?

Can PipelineDB JOIN to regular SQL VIEWs, so, in essence the SQL VIEW is updated automatically each time the underlying data is changed?

Answer (score 0):

1. PipelineDB allows you to `JOIN` on as many tables as you'd like, including with other continuous views or regular views. The only thing you can't `JOIN` with a stream is another stream (no stream-stream `JOINs`).
2. Whatever "reference data" exists at `JOIN` time is what will be used to update the continuous view. In other words, updating reference data after the fact will not automatically change historic data in the continuous view, but new incoming rows will reflect the updated reference data.

Here's an example of a continuous view definition which contains multiple `JOINs`:

https://github.com/pipelinedb/pipelinedb/blob/master/src/test/regress/sql/stream_table_join.sql#L61

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks for clarifying Derek.  Is there an example you could post showing multiple JOINs to 2+ reference tables?  I could not find any in the current docs or examples.

Comment: Sure, I added a link to a test with an example. Feel free to reach out to us (Gittr is probably the best) if you need help constructing your particular CV, we're happy to help.